Cannot build jupyterlab extension
I run command  jupyter lab build --dev-build=False --minimize=False in conda prompt to build jupyter lab but failed.
jupyter lab version: 2.2.6
Actually, I want to use ipywidgets extension of jupyter lab, but I found that the failure of lab building is the main problem.  The final result in conda prompt is

An error occured.
RuntimeError: JupyterLab failed to build.
See the log file for details:  C:\Users\lcg19\AppData\Local\Temp\jupyterlab-debug-qc969dp0.log

The whole log file is:
[LabBuildApp] Building in C:\Anaconda\share\jupyter\lab
[LabBuildApp] Node v20.12.2

[LabBuildApp] Yarn configuration loaded.
[LabBuildApp] Building jupyterlab assets (build:prod)
[LabBuildApp] > node C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\staging\yarn.js install --non-interactive
[LabBuildApp] yarn install v1.21.1
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 1.32s.

[LabBuildApp] > node C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\staging\yarn.js yarn-deduplicate -s fewer --fail
[LabBuildApp] yarn run v1.21.1
$ C:\Anaconda\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\.bin\yarn-deduplicate -s fewer --fail
Done in 1.10s.

[LabBuildApp] > node C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\staging\yarn.js run build:prod
[LabBuildApp] yarn run v1.21.1
$ ensure-max-old-space webpack --config webpack.prod.config.js
node:child_process:929
    throw err;
    ^

<ref *1> Error: spawnSync C:\Anaconda\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\.bin\webpack.CMD EINVAL
    at Object.spawnSync (node:internal/child_process:1124:20)
    at spawnSync (node:child_process:876:24)
    at Object.execFileSync (node:child_process:919:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Anaconda\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\@jupyterlab\buildutils\lib\ensure-max-old-space.js:38:17)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1369:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1427:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1206:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  errno: -4071,
  code: 'EINVAL',
  syscall: 'spawnSync C:\\Anaconda\\share\\jupyter\\lab\\staging\\node_modules\\.bin\\webpack.CMD',
  path: 'C:\\Anaconda\\share\\jupyter\\lab\\staging\\node_modules\\.bin\\webpack.CMD',
  spawnargs: [ '--config', 'webpack.prod.config.js' ],
  error: [Circular *1],
  status: null,
  signal: null,
  output: null,
  pid: 0,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null
}

Node.js v20.12.2
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

[LabBuildApp] JupyterLab failed to build
[LabBuildApp] Traceback (most recent call last):

[LabBuildApp]   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\debuglog.py", line 47, in debug_logging
    yield

[LabBuildApp]   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\labapp.py", line 138, in start
    raise e

[LabBuildApp]   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\labapp.py", line 134, in start
    build(name=self.name, version=self.version,

[LabBuildApp]   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", line 459, in build
    return handler.build(name=name, version=version, static_url=static_url,

[LabBuildApp]   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", line 661, in build
    raise RuntimeError(msg)

[LabBuildApp] RuntimeError: JupyterLab failed to build

[LabBuildApp] Exiting application: JupyterLab


Can anybody tell me what's wrong with my jupyter lab building and how to fix this problem?
I've found a similar question as mine Jupyterlab Plotly extension install: JupyterLab failed to build but my error is slightly different(mine throw error in node child process 929) and his question hasn't been solved.

Oh wait. jupyter lab version: 2.2.6??!?! That is super old & not even listed on the changelog. You would indeed need to build for that but it won't work with current ipywidgets. Please update by uninstalling the Anaconda Distribution and reinstalling. (It's still a little odd that Anaconda is not in the path of C:\Users\lcg19\AppData\Local\Temp\jupyterlab-debug-qc969dp0.log.)

I'm just using jupyter Lab. I already use command pip install ipywidgets to install ipywidgets in jupter lab AND it runs well. But I cannot get the interactive buttons in the jupyter lab, which is what I really expect. I suspect installing ipywidgets package in jupyter lab is the same as your conda install conda-forge::ipywidgets code? Sorry for misinterpretations if any.

No, mixing pip and conda is not the same. And should not be done. If you choose to use Anaconda/conda then it becomes your primary package manager and should be used to install everything. Only ever fall back to installing with pip for things that have no conda recipe.

"But I cannot get the interactive buttons in the jupyter lab," Did you restart everythng? And I mean everything. Ideally your entire machine. It really has a lot of layers that it affects. It's not like most packages where you can install with the magic commands inside a running notebook and not even restart. "ipywidgets in jupter lab AND it runs well. But I cannot get the interactive buttons in the jupyter lab, which is what I really expect." Those statements are juxtaposed. If ipywidgets installed and works well then the interactive buttons would show up. If you don't need really old ...

 versions of things, I would suggest at this point you'd be better off uninstalling and cleaning out your old Anaconda installation. Move any enviornments you made though as backup unless you don't care about them? Then install the new version of The Anaconda Distribution. It will come with more current versions and ipywidgets is already installed there and working in the Anaconda Distribution base. Please read about how to use your environments though so you know to only use Anaconda/conda to change things.

pip install for extensions works only since JupyterLab 3. JupyterLab 2.x is out of support, and you really should not use it (in the literal sense that security fixes were not backported to it).
